# How to catch runtime error from a function invoked from a waitgroup?

Tags: go, concurrency

How to handle crashes in a waitgroup gracefully?

In other words, in the following snippet of code, how to catch the panics/crashes of goroutines invoking method `do()`?

```
func do(){
    str := "abc"
    fmt.Print(str[3])
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Print(err)
        }
    }()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go do()
        defer func() {
            wg.Done()
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                fmt.Print(err)
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("This line should be printed after all those invocations fail.")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, registering a deferred function to recover should be the first line in the function, as since you do it last, it won't even be reached because the line / code before the `defer` already panics and so the deferred function does not get registered which would restore the panicing state.

So change your `do()` function to this:

```
func do() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Restored:", err)
        }
    }()
    str := "abc"
    fmt.Print(str[3])
}
```

Second: this alone will not make your code work, as you call `wg.Defer()` in a deferred function which would only run once `main()` finishes - which is never because you call `wg.Wait()` in your `main()`. So `wg.Wait()` waits for the `wg.Done()` calls, but `wg.Done()` calls will not be run until `wg.Wait()` returnes. It's a deadlock.

You should call `wg.Done()` from the `do()` function, in the deferred function, something like this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func do() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
    str := "abc"
    fmt.Print(str[3])
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go do()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("This line should be printed after all those invocations fail.")
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/VN7Lh7hCG1)):

```
Restored: runtime error: index out of range
This line should be printed after all those invocations fail.
```

This of course needed to move the `wg` variable to global scope. Another option would be to pass it to `do()` as an argument. If you decide to go this way, note that you have to pass a pointer to [`WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), else only a copy will be passed (`WaitGroup` is a `struct` type) and calling `WaitGroup.Done()` on a copy will not have effect on the original.

With passing `WaitGroup` to `do()`:

```
func do(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Restored:", err)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
    str := "abc"
    fmt.Print(str[3])
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go do(&wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("This line should be printed after all those invocations fail.")
}
```

Output is the same. Try this variant on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/D5l95GQAkN).

Answer (score 0):

@icza did a fantastic job explaining how to appropriately use `WaitGroup` and its functions `Wait` and `Done`

I like `WaitGroup` simplicity. However, I do not like that we need to pass the reference to the goroutine because that would mean that the concurrency logic would be mixed with your business logic.

So I came up with this generic function to solve this problem for me:

```
// Parallelize parallelizes the function calls
func Parallelize(functions ...func()) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(len(functions))

    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    for _, function := range functions {
        go func(copy func()) {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            copy()
        }(function)
    }
}
```

So your example could be solved this way:

```
func do() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    str := "abc"
    fmt.Print(str[3])
}

func main() {
    Parallelize(do, do, do)

    fmt.Println("This line should be printed after all those invocations fail.")
}
```

If you would like to use it, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util